# Le gérondif ("en" + le participe en "-ant")

Tags: grammaire, en

Would you agree with me that the author of the following article missed an "en" in the second paragraph, between Mauerpark and se? Without the "en", it seems that the two men who got approached were the ones pretending to be policemen.

> Ainsi, ils auraient abordé deux hommes dans le Mauerpark se présentant comme des policiers chargés de surveiller l’application des gestes barrières. Ils ont exigé de leurs victimes 1.000 euros d’amende pour violation du règlement en vigueur et sont allés jusqu’à fouiller l'un des passants.

https://fr.sputniknews.com/europe/202011281044847987-des-escrocs-tentent-dinfliger-des-amendes-aux-passants-pour-violation-des-mesures-de-restriction-a/

Comment: I misunderstood your question and I gave a (now deleted) wrong answer. Yes, after reading the article, I agree with your affirmation: the "ils" is the "faux policiers" and should therefore be the subject.

Comment: This sentence could work if you add a comma between "Mauerpark" and "se": "Ainsi, ils auraient abordé deux hommes dans le Mauerpark, se présentant comme des policiers chargés de surveiller l’application des gestes barrières."

Answer (score 6):

En effet, il manque la préposition "**en**" avant "se présentant": "**en** se présentant".
Comme le dit vc74 dans son commentaire, une **virgule** avant "se présentant" est tout à fait possible aussi: "dans le Mauerpark, se présentant comme..."

Attention, "se présentant" n'est pas un **gérondif**, comme l'annonce le titre de votre question, mais un **participe présent**, ce qui n'est pas la même chose.

Comment: Simplement pour énoncer explicitement ce point : le *gérondif* désigne le fait d'utiliser la préposition "en" suivie d'un participe présent.